# Intellij import class does not import properly with a gradle project

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

When I try to import any class intellij tries to import main.java as a prefix. It's not suppose to show that since the srcs root is src/main/java

This is what my issue looks like.
[image]

My build.gradle looks like this.

```
group = 'rsam'
version = '1.00'
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21'

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-compress
compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-compress', version: '1.13'

}

sourceSets {
main.java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/test/java']
main.resources.srcDirs = ['resources']
}
```

Comment: Indeed, it shouldn't. Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @CrazyCoder I would but that type of example does not reproduce the problem. The issue is how the gradle project is imported because if I create a new gradle project with minimal code it works. Go figure